# node.js add click event

Tags: node.js, events, click

I am trying to make click event on page using cherio npm package but since click is not an option for Jquery i try to save html file first. Than i am adding regular jquery code with click() but not sure about next page load and node element already clicked.

Regards,
Take  look at the sample:

```
request(desk["url"], function (error, response, body) {
desk["body"]=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load(desk["body"]);
fs.appendFile(desk["body"], "<script>jQuery('#contacts a').click()</script>", function (err) {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
   console.log('Appended!');
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to use Node.js to visit `desk.url` and simulate a click event on `#contacts a`?

Comment: yeap.Then parse the data but it is hidden without click event. Therefore the question is how to make click event on hyperlink on client side.

Comment: You will need to use a browser automation library, such as `nightmare` or `phantomjs`. From the above code snippet, you were just downloading the HTML response from some url, then append some string to the body, there is no any JavaScript event involved in the runtime.

Comment: Also, I believe `body` is the HTML string, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));` should throw error. And for best practice, avoid using `require` inside a function call, dependencies should be placed at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks Kit. Will dig on Phantom.js deeper. Seems like it is what i am looking for. Will write back with results since it is not enlightened good.

Comment: I prefer `nightmare` because it has higher level APIs and your code will look cleaner.

Comment: One more i have found .Take a look at headless chrome api.

Comment: Do you mean `puppeteer`?

Comment: Yep. It is good enough to parse web sites.